# Brave don't start

Tags: brave

I have a ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, and after upgrade Ubuntu Brave browser don't open anymore.

```
brave-browser-stable                 
[237239:237239:0318/160044.264043:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(377)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

I did remove the folder `~/.config/BraveSoftware`, uninstall/reinstall `apt remove --purge brave-browser` and `apt remove --purge brave-browser` and dosen't worked.

I tryied with `brave-browser-stable --disable-gpu` and `brave-browser --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer` but same error

I was googled but nothing worked.

Comment: I installed with `sudo snap install brave` and worked. What happens?

Comment: refer [https://community.brave.com/t/error-while-installing-brave-browser-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts/191822]

Comment: Did you add Brave via the recommended method on the brave website? They recommend against using the snap at the moment (see: https://brave.com/linux/#release-channel-installation). If you are going to try to uninstall then reinstall, maybe start with this; https://support.brave.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404876135565-How-do-I-uninstall-Brave-